# How to get parent class from child class in Typescript?

Tags: typescript, inheritance

I'm working with typescript in a client-side framework and I have the following classes:

```
Guest{
    name:string
    firstName:string
    email:string
    ....
}
```

and there is a child class:

```
GuestForm extends Guest{
    nameError:string
    firstNameError:string
    emailError:string
    ....
}
```

I use the GuestForm class in a form. When everything is valid, I would like to send the guest information to a back-end.
I will not cover all my logic but the guest informations must be in another class before to send it.
So I create a GuestInfo class:

```
GuestInfo{
    guest: Guest
    ...
}
```

and when I try to create a instance of GuestInfo:

```
const guestError = new GuestError();
const guestInfo = new GuestInfo(guestError);
```

and that I console.log the guestInfo class, it contains a instance of GuestError and not an instance of Guest.
So I will send too many informations to the back-end and it's not really the result I expected when I wrote that.

If someone has any idea to help me or explainations about this behaviour, I'll take it.

Thank you and have a nice day,

Dimitri

Comment: It seems that you pass GuestError() instance to your GuestInfo, why do you think it should contain Guest? Could you please put some details of your implementation since now it is hard to reason about it.

Answer (score 1):

As Shlang said, it's logic that I have a GuestError instance. The problem is still the same, I send to much information to the back-end.

After some research, I find that when you use JSON.stringify with "undefined" properties, it doesn't include it in the json.

When I send the form, I switch all my errors properties to "undefined" and I use JSON.stringify and everything works as I want.